# centos 7 replace systemd with a script

Tags: linux, bash, console, init, systemd

I want to do the following thing: I want to replace the *systemd* program on my *CentOS 7* installation, with a *script*, that will eventually start a shell where the user can input commands as root on the system console.

For this, I used the *init=/sbin/myInit* parameter. In this script I do some initialization, and in the end I call *bash* to enable the user to input commands. The interactive bash always appears on the screen.

Unfortunately, there is a problem with the input, that I haven't been able to solve: the input doesn't work correctly. When I press enter, only the second enter works, but no new line is performed on the screen. And when I type some characters, not all the characters are read. It seems like the console is in some Unicode mode (*stty -a* shows *iutf8* parameter), and bash cannot correctly read the input. The output is fine, all the *echo* commands in my script are correctly printed on the screen (I only print ASCII characters).

I've tried all sorts of combinations, with different *LC_ALL* settings (*LC_ALL=C*, *LC_ALL=C.utf-8*, no *LC_ALL* or *LANG* variables initialization), redirect *stdin/stdout/stderr* to */dev/console*, */dev/tty0* or */dev/tty1*, the *TERM* variable is initialized to *linux* value, but nothing works. I tried *unicode_start* and *unicode_stop* commands, but *unicode_stop* doesn't work, and I get the error message "stty: standard input: unable to perform all requested operations". If I run showkey command, and I press the enter key, the correct keycode 28 is detected, same with normal boot.

Even stranger than this is the fact that if I'm using the *init=/bin/bash* kernel parameter, the input works fine, and if I manually run my script, it also works fine. If I copy the bash executable to something like */bin/mys*, and I use *init=/bin/mys*, than same input problem occurs. It seems like the initrd image treats */bin/bash* differently. Maybe it performs some initialization or something, that enables the bash to read correctly from the terminal. Why do we have this difference between *init=/bin/bash* and *init=/bin/mys*? It's the same executable in the end.

What am I doing wrong ?

As a general question about the *init* program, can somebody explain me what the init program should do to work correctly ?  Any particular signals it has to respond to, any console initialization to be performed ?

I'm trying to solve this for days, and I cannot find any solution. On the web I couldn't find any article about this. So any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to pull a solution out for this one.

Turns out, at boot, the console is not initialized. I looked at the differences between the output of *stty -a* between the normal boot and the script boot (*init=/sbin/myInit*), and there are some differences between them: the console on normal boot had the following flags active on it: brkint ignpar ixon imaxbell isig icanon iexten echo, while when on script boot, those flags where cleared (*stty* reports them with - ). I'm not sure what they mean, except the echo flag, which I quickly noticed, because on each key press, no character ware printed on the screen.

So I decided to set those flags on my init script for /dev/console. After digging the *stty* manual page, I found the *sane* option, that sets the most important flags for normal console usage. So I added the line *stty -F /dev/console sane* in my init script.

But, there is a small problem. It seems that some console options cannot be changed by the *stty* command if the console is already opened by a process. So the first thing I did in my script is to redirect the *stdin/stdout/stderr* to */dev/null*, via the line *0/dev/null*, and then add the *stty sane* line, then redirect back the *stdin/stdout/stderr* to */dev/console*.

I also noticed a process called *plymouth*, probably started by the CentOS *initrd*, so before the root was mounted and init script executed. I'm not sure if that process opened the system console, but I decided to eliminate it, by reconstructing a personalized *initrd*, by omitting the *plymouth* module from *dracut* (option *-o plymouth*).

After doing this, the script worked fine, and the bash process started by the script could read correctly the console.

Hope this helps somebody someday. Cheers